# What was the role (if any) of Jesuits at the Lycée Louis-Barthou when Guy Debord was a pupil there?

Tags: france

French Situationist [Guy Debord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy_Debord) (1931-94) was a pupil at the [Lycée Louis-Barthou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyc%C3%A9e_Louis-Barthou) in Pau, southern France. The school was founded by Jesuits in 1640 after a grant of letters patent in 1620. ([Source](https://www.lyceelouisbarthou.fr/informations/c/0/i/43544310/le-lycee-barthou-de-1620-1966).)

What was the role at the school of Jesuits, if any, when Debord was a pupil there, which presumably was in the 1940s?